# Bounty points from another site

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties, rep-transfer

I've seen some previous questions about transferring points between sites. They are usually quite unequivocally answered that points should not be transferrable, for fairly obvious reasons such as reputation as a programmer not being equivalent to that of a cook.

However, I would like to request that it be possible to bounty points on any site. When setting bounties, there doesn't seem to be a good reason not to allow points from other sites to be used because you are not misrepresenting your own reputation.

I could imagine a problem if it was possible to accumulate disproportionate reputation on some sites and use that as currency elsewhere. I do not think this is generally the case - it is easiest to accumulate points on the larger sites anyway, where the points themselves are most 'trusted'.